# I'm using a flex box to display label and input field. How do I make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to use a flex class to make a label and input field one line. How do I force it to be responsive?

My HTML Code is

```css
.container{
  width:1100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.form_single_wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.form_single_wrap label{
  width:10%;
}
.form_single_wrap input{
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="form_wrap"> 
    <form action=" ">
      <div class="form_single_wrap"> 
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form_single_wrap"> 
        <label for="email">Email Send Us</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>
```

How can I make it responsive?

You can see in [codepan](https://codepen.io/xossarif/pen/RyZLBQ)

Comment: max-width instead of width within a container

Comment: In bootstrap what I need to do ?

Comment: in bootstrap, simply remove the fixed width you defined

Comment: its giving me -> https://codepen.io/xossarif/pen/odeoqP

Answer (score 0):

Use % instead of px for the container :)

```
.container{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: i would say "cheh"

Answer (score 0):

I fix it also in bootstrap. You can see in [codepen](https://codepen.io/xossarif/pen/odeoqP)

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <style type="text/css">
    .form_wrap{
      width:100%;
    }
   .form_single_wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .form_single_wrap label{
    width:10%;
   }
   .form_single_wrap input{
    width:80%;
   } 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="form_wrap"> 
    <form action=" ">
     <div class="form_single_wrap"> 
      <label for="name">Name </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form_single_wrap"> 
      <label for="email">Email Send Us</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>   
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```